# Do green powders maintain nutritional values?

Tags: micronutrients, coloration-discoloration, nutrition, labeling, meal-replacement

I really love to drink green smoothies.
I usually put in a generous amount of fresh parsley or fresh spinach leaves and I like it very much.

I saw that you can buy some green powders in order to mix in with the smoothies, these powders are a blend of multiple greens.

My question is - **Do these powders have the nutritional values of fresh green leaves?**

Comment: The nutritional value of anything brought in packet form is determined by the rules of the individuals countries food standards. UK and USA both have stringent requirements that mean the exact nutritional information is on the labelling. Trust the label.